# JavaScript Function Returns Multiple Values as Object in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function function_name()
{
    var a=1;
    var b=2;

    return {a, b} 
}

let {p1, q1} = function_name()
```

Why do I get an error message about the values of `p1`, `q1` as `undefined`? However, the below code gives the expected results:

```
 var o = {p: 42, q: true};
 var {p, q} = o;

 console.log(p); // 42
 console.log(q); // true
```

Can any one please explain the difference between the two code examples?

Comment: Are you using babel transpiler or not ? Which browser with version you are testing on ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are getting desired output because function_name() is returning an object that is having two variables a and b having some value.

```
function function_name()
{
    var a=1;var b=2;
    return {a,b} 
}
```

here `return {a, b}` is equivalent to `return {a: a, b: b}` is equivalent to `return {a: 1, b: 2}`

To get the exact value you need to update your calling method signature to:

```
let {a, b} = function_name()
```

**Note**: It is not a good practice to use a or b as variable name. You should use valid names.

Answer (score 5):

It is a destructuring, which uses the keys in the curly bracket for getting the values with the same key of the assignment. Your function retuns an object

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 }
```

and then you want to get the properties with the names `p1` and `p2`. Obviously there are no keys with this names in the object and therefor no property in the result.

```
{ a: 1, b: 2 } => get { p1 and p2 } => {}
```

Working example

```
{ p: 42, q: true } => get { p and q } => { p: 42, q: true }
```

With another property

```
{ p: 42, q: true, foo: 42 } => get { p and q } => { p: 42, q: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use like this**

```
function function_name()
{
    var a=1;
    var b=2;

    return [a, b] 
}

let [p1, q1] = function_name()
```

return multiple values as array

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain the question from the OP at all. Also, in general providing a code example is good, but it should be a) as simple as possible and b) the code example should be accompanied by an explanation as to why your example works and that from the OP doesn't work.